# Jboss 5. HttpOnly session cookies

Tags: java, session-cookies, jboss5.x

How to configure JBoss 5.1.* to make session cookie HttpOnly?

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true">
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```

as explained [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/598558).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using JBoss [EAP] 5.0.1 and adding

```
<SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```

in <myJBossServerInstancePath>/deploy/jbossweb.sar/context.xml

```
<Context cookies="true" crossContext="true">
    <SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
    ...
```

works perfectly (thanks Luciano).

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```

In $JBOSS_HOME/deploy/jbossweb.sar/context.xml

```
<Context cookies="true" crossContext="true">
   <SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```

Make sure HTTPS/SSL configured in the server to work.