# HttpOnly settings can be done in application having servlet api-2.5 and web.xml 2.5 version?

Tags: security, cookie-httponly

wanna enable httpOnly attribute to session cookie for our application. we are using servlet-api 2.5 version and web.xml as 2.5 .. now i have tried adding below code in web.xml

```
<cookie-config>
 <http-only>true</http-only>
</cookie-config>
```

i got error parsing error in `web.xml` at `<cookie-config>`

can any please help on this.. do i need to update servlet version to 3 and web.xml to 3 as well ...

or any other ways to do it writing in java code itself.. we are using jboss 5 version..

Comment: You can only do it in a container-specific way unless you are using version 3. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457204/jboss-5-httponly-session-cookies).

Comment: Tried adding below changes and i was not able to login to application itself...<SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" /> in &lt;myJBossServerInstancePath&gt;/deploy/jbossweb.sar/context.xml <Context cookies="true" crossContext="true"> <SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" /> ...

Comment: Why "secure"? Are you using HTTPS? Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: we are not using HTTPS , so in this case u want me to add only       ...<SessionCookie  httpOnly="true" />  ?   Thanks

Comment: Thank you Taylor it worked... Can you please tell me how to test this scenario whether httpOnly is set or not for session cookies...

Comment: Try accessing it from Javascript, perhaps? Or check the header has the "HttpOnly" attribute set? If you know what it means in practice (and you should) then you should be able to test it.